# Radiation Pressure at oblique incidence

Tags: pressure, radiation, radiation-pressure

[image]

**Consider case of absorption**

Here the force due to light is given by $F=\frac{IA\cos\theta}{c}$

This force is perpendicular to the surface.

So the pressure due to this force should be $\frac{F}{A}$, but it's actually $\frac{F\cos\theta}{A}$.

Why are we again multiplying $F$ by $\cos\theta$ when $F$ found out earlier is already perpendicular to the surface?

**Now in case of Reflection**

$F=\frac{2IA\cos^2\theta}{c}$
and $P=\frac{F}{A}$

Why here $P = \frac{F\cos\theta}{A}$?

Answer (score 1):

In case of absorption, the first cos theta comes because the area of cross section of the beam which is incident on the surface is A cos theta. The second one comes to take the component of force perpendicular to the surface.

For reflecting surface the same force is doubled.